# Update Parents table status

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

what i want trying to do is to update my child table when my parents status is "Deleted"

**Parents Table**

```
-------------
PID | CID |Pstatus
1   |  1  | Deleted
2   |  1  | Active
3   |  2  | Deleted
4   |  2  | Deleted
```

the logic behind is like below

```
IF CID = 1 and PsTatus = deleted

Update ChildTableStatus
Set Status = 'Deleted'
Where CID = 1

Else

cannot update childtablestatus to deleted due to there are active records
```

how to perform a looping check over here?

Comment: Please show us the schema for `ChildTableStatus` and explain the relationship between the tables.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that "ChildTableStatus" actually refers to the same table.  You are just looking for the right filtering expression in that case:

```
update parents
    set status = 'deleted'
    where exists (select 1 from parents p2 where p2.cid = p.pid and p2.status = 'deleted')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following DML should be better than using the nested queries such as EXISTS or IN as they bring down the performance.

```
Update p1
Set p1.Status = 'Deleted'
FROM Parents p1 JOIN Parents p2
ON p1.pid = p2.cid
Where p2.status = 'Deleted'
```

- This is assuming you are trying to do the update on same table. Otherwise, just change the table name in **FROM** clause.

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
Update ChildTableStatus
Set Status = 'Deleted'
Where CID = (Select CID from Parents where Pstatus = 'deleted')
```